# Nodejs- capturing business events - http,http outbound

Tags: node.js, http, npm

I am trying to capture business events - APIs (http-GET and http outbound- POST,PUT) and I am using appmetrics package but it capures events of http request of page

But it is not capturing all API calls made and posting data

```
const appmetrics = require('appmetrics');
const monitoring = appmetrics.monitor();
const request    = require('request');
const http = require("http");
const metrics = require('./index.js');

module.exports = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8083);

request
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
  })

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

appmetrics.enable('http');
appmetrics.enable('request');
monitoring.on('request', function (request) {
        console.log('request', request);
});
monitoring.on('http', function (http) {
        console.log('http', http);
});
```

Above appmetrics captures only page requests but not all api GET calls from this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'request' in appmetrics is not actually related to the request module, it means something else.  Add `monitoring.on('http-outbound', ...)`
to record outgoing http calls and make sure you put it before your call to `request.get`, e.g.

```
const appmetrics = require('appmetrics');
const monitoring = appmetrics.monitor();
const request    = require('request');
const http = require("http");
const metrics = require('./index.js');


monitoring.on('http', function (http) {
    console.log('http', http);
});


monitoring.on('http-outbound', function (http) {
    console.log('http-outbound', http);
});

module.exports = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8083);

request
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
  })

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```